# Inverse limit of closed intervals which is open?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers, limits-colimits

Is there an easy (but nontrivial) example of an inverse limit of real, closed intervals, which is an open interval, and for which at least one of the 
projections is a surjection ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

An inverse limit of compact Hausdorff spaces is compact, because the product of those spaces is compact (by Tychonoff's Theorem) and Hausdorff, and the inverse limit is a closed subset of the product. So no, this is not possible.